# JSON Hijacking Prevention with BackboneJS and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, backbone.js

I have been reading a lot about JSON Hijacking and a lot of the articles are dated a while back.

I wonder if this is still a threat with modern browsers.

If it is, how do I solve  it using NOdeJS and BackboneJS? I mean, I know about all the methods that people normally uses to avoid it like '//', 'while(true);', 'for(;;);' but not sure how I would implement it with NodeJS which sends back a response using res.json({object}) and how i would filter these prefixes on BackboneJS using fetch?

I'm trying to build a safe app here, hence all those questions.

Any help, opinion or suggestion would be awesome. :)

Some references I found was:
http://ilee.co.uk/hack-to-prevent-json-hijacking/
http://blackbe.lt/safely-handling-json-hijacking-prevention-methods-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a string with literal "\u2029" character somewhere in it.

Since JSON isn't a proper subset of a javascript, javascript parser will raise SyntaxError in there, but it can still be parsed by an ordinary JSON.parse() function.